# Usando for loop em uma lista com gráficos no R

Tags: r, for

Esse é o meu codigo:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:100,
                 y1 = runif(100),
                 y2 = runif(100)^2)

plot_list <- list(
  plot1 = ggplot(df, aes(x, y1)) + geom_point(),
  plot2 = ggplot(df, aes(x, y2)) + geom_point()
)
```

O que eu preciso é acessar cada plot nessa lista utilizando um for loop juntamente com `x11()`:

```
for (i in 1:length(plot_list)) {

  x11()

  plot_list[i]

}
```

Por que não funciona?

Alguma ajuda?

Obrigada!

Laura

Comment: Troque `plot_list[i]` por `print(plot_list[[i]])` ou `show(plot_list[[i]])`. Ahhh e você tá no stack em português, acho q se confundiu na língua do post kkk

Comment: @JorgeMendes nem percebi!! kkkk vou fazer a tradução kkk

Comment: @JorgeMendes muito obrigada!!

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do Jorge Mendes está certa, o código deve ser:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:100,
                 y1 = runif(100),
                 y2 = runif(100)^2)

plot_list <- list(
  plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y1)) + geom_point(),
  plot2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y2)) + geom_point()
)

for (i in 1:length(plot_list)) {

  x11()

  show(plot_list[[i]])

}
```

=)

Answer (score 0):

Além da resposta do Ícaro Agostinho, você pode utilizar a família apply, que é mais performático que o loop for:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:100,
                 y1 = runif(100),
                 y2 = runif(100)^2)

plot_list <- list(
  plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y1)) + geom_point(),
  plot2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y2)) + geom_point()
)

lapply(plot_list, function(x){
  x11()
  show(x)
})
```